# How to select only numbers from a dataframe in R using which()

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-types

I have a large dataframe in R  and am trying to do some stats tests on certain columns, but the non-programmers who made the csv file added a bunch of text notes that I need to ignore.

For example a column might have values:  12,20,40,missing,64,32,no input,45,10

How do I only select the numbers using the which statement?
I failed miserably trying:
my_data_frame$Column.Title[which(is.numeric(my_data_frame$Column.Title))]

What do I change in the which function to only select the numbers and ignore the text? Thanks!

Comment: `which(sapply(myframe, is.numeric))` returns integers, column-indices of numeric columns.

Comment: But since you're looking at `my_data_frame$Column.Title`, it sounds like you're misunderstanding something about R's data.frames: a column is ***all one class***. That means that if the first value is `numeric` (whether `NA` or not), then the entire column is `numeric`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `as.numeric()` converter to do something like this:

```
x <- my_data_frame$Column.Title
xn <- as.numeric(x)
which(!is.na(xn))
```

This won't distinguish between `NA`s created by failed coercion and pre-existing (numeric) `NA` values.

If there's a small enough variety of "missing" values you could read the data in with `read.csv(..., na.strings=c("NA","missing","no input"))`